# Visual Studio's terminal stops opening when the debugger is launched

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, console, mean-stack

I use Visual Studio's Node debugger on a website on the MEAN stack (Typescript on server side, Angular 2 on client side).

I was used to see VS terminal open when I "Run: script dev" and see the logs scroll in it.

Since yesterday, running the debugger makes nothing happen in the terminal.

I've tried to:

- reboot VS
- reboot the laptop
- remove, autoremove, purge and reinstall VS
  But the problem remains.

However it still works on my back-up laptop.

I really need to debug.

configuration:

- Ubuntu 22
- Visual Studio 1.71.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to last VS Code version: it works with the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you have added commands in your launch.json

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO6n1.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).